# how to select random faces but not vertices or edges

Tags: selection-tools

im trying to make something and I want to randomly select only the faces not the edges

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make sure to be in *face* selection mode before random deselect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blender will random select/deselect depending on the selection mode (vertex, edge, face). Here you have to use *face selection* mode.

- Select a top face.
- Select similar faces, to select them all.
- Then use *'select random'* and use *'deselect'* option

[image]